# Spring WebClient annotated connectexception" connection refused " and going indefinatatly in the logs

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

please help us on this issue we have two services a, b a is trying to call b service when is down and now a continuously logging error indefinitely.it should not do

it should only log once, its keep increaing logs and going for tose.we are using springboot-starter-webflux 2.7.8